# Is there a way to make a function to test the ssh connect-ability of devices on the network without typing in the individual device?

Tags: python, ssh

I am working on a program where connecting over SSH to a raspberry pi is necessary to run the program through my GUI app window in python, here is what I have right now to "test" ssh connections on all devices but i have to type in the actual IP of the pi itself. I need to make this where it just tests connection of everything on the network and connects to the available device.

Any help?

```
def raspi_connecter():
    for n in range(1, 255):
        server_ip= "10.0.0.153".format(n)
        subprocess.Popen('ssh' + ' ' + 'dev@' + server_ip, shell= True)
```

Comment: Use this: https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/

Comment: That still requires the IP address to be entered in, though.

Comment: You can do that with python. ```#!/usr/bin/python
from pyroute2 import IPRoute #
import socket #
ip = IPRoute() #
for x in ip.get_addr(label='eth0',family=socket.AF_INET):
  ipa =x.get_attr('IFA_ADDRESS')+"/"+str(x['prefixlen'])
```

Comment: @Dougie - post that as an answer?

Comment: @Dougie that is still not working for me, i get the following error: "Address family not supported by protocol family"

Comment: One problem is that you keep hitting 10.0.0.153 over and over. The format string should be `server_ip= "10.0.0.{}".format(n)`.

Comment: @tdelaney I did that, thank you. What I am trying to do now though is eliminate having "10" in there as well, as if the IP was not known at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's python**2** program (I've never reworked it for python3) that finds your Raspberries. It runs nmap to create XML output then crudely parses that.

It needs the iproute module `sudo apt install python{,3}-pyroute`

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from pyroute2 import IPRoute
import socket
import subprocess
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ip = IPRoute()
for x in ip.get_addr(label='eth0',family=socket.AF_INET):
  ipa =x.get_attr('IFA_ADDRESS')+"/"+str(x['prefixlen'])

print ipa
process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','nmap','-oX', '/tmp/nmap.xml','-sn',ipa],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()

tree = ET.parse('/tmp/nmap.xml')
for node in tree.iter('address'):
    try:
        if node.attrib['addrtype'] == "ipv4":
        ip = node.attrib['addr']
    except:
        pass
    try:
        if node.attrib['vendor'] == "Raspberry Pi Foundation":
        print "IP:", ip
    except:
        pass
```

Once you have an IP address for a Raspberry then you can run ssh with subprocess (or ping or netcat). It will need additional testing for Raspberry Pi 4 and Pi400 devices (as I don't have either of those (which use the new MAC OUI).